# How do I display output of users who are logged in the server in the vi editor?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, vi

I have an assignment for my unix/linux course to create a shell script and display output for whether a certain user is logged in or not. We were assigned lab partners and we exchanged usernames for this assignment because we need to determine whether our lab partners are logged into the system by using a shell script. If it's relevant, I'm using a bash shell. I tried using the who command in the editor, but it doesn't recognize it as a command. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the VI (or better in VIM) editor, then you can:

1) `:!who` to run the `who` command in the shell

2) in command mode `:.!who` to do the same and paste the result to the current curspor position

3) write a vi function to execute and handle the results of `who` and use it with `call` call which can take a parameter of the interesting user name or whatever.

Some examples: https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-tips-working-external-commands

If you are in the command line, then `who | vi -` will open the vi editor and insert the result of the `who`. You can also play with `-c` option to vi to combine the examples above. 
Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ps -o user= -p $$ | awk '{print $1}'` or `echo $SUDO_USER` or `echo $user` or `w` or `users`